# Failure to return file paths in server 2008 qt QDirIterator

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qdir

I want to see the whole path of a drive, I did it on Windows 8 and 9, the paths are displayed correctly.

But in Windows 2003 and 2008, the paths are not displayed, what's the problem?
My code

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtCore>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QDirIterator it("C:/",QStringList() << "*",  QDir::Files , QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        qDebug() << it.next();
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

picture app

[image]